# Executing Dockerfile in Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to run Dockerfile in Jenkinsfile pipeline.
I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV VERSION=1.2.0
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python vim zip unzip
RUN mkdir -p /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY zip_job.py ./
RUN cat /etc/lsb-release
RUN uname -m
RUN ls -l /tmp
```

This is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    stages { 
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'python zip_job.py'
            }
        }
        stage('Publish') {
            steps {
                rtServer (
                    id: 'Artifactory-1',
                    url: 'https://aidock.jfrog.io/artifactory/devops-assignment/',
                    username: 'super-user'
                    password: 'Qw12856!'
                )
                rtUpload (
                    serverId: 'Artifactory-1',
                    spec: '''{
                          "files": [
                            {
                              "pattern": "tmp/*.zip",
                              "target": "binary-storage/1.2.0
                            }
                        ]
                  }''',
                )
            }
        }
        stage('Report') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
        stage('Cleanup') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

My working directory in Docker should be /tmp.
When running a build I get the following error:

```
 Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/My-Pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Agent Setup)
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t b96873ea12524b982ef8ce77660ade7f3744e812 -f Dockerfile .
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/My-Pipeline@tmp/durable-f53af459/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/My-Pipeline@tmp/durable-f53af459/script.sh: docker: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Tried almost every trick in the book but yet it is not working.
Docker Plugins are installed.

Appreciate the help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the Pipeline, or stage, with a container built from a Dockerfile contained in the source repository.
In order to use this option, the Jenkinsfile must be loaded from either a Multibranch Pipeline or a Pipeline from SCM.
Conventionally this is the Dockerfile in the root of the source repository: agent { dockerfile true }.
If building a Dockerfile in another directory, use the dir option: agent { dockerfile { dir 'someSubDir' } }.
If your Dockerfile has another name, you can specify the file name with the filename option.
You can pass additional arguments to the docker build …​command with the additionalBuildArgs option, like agent { dockerfile { additionalBuildArgs '--build-arg foo=bar' } }. For example, a repository with the file build/Dockerfile.build, expecting a build argument version:

```
agent {
    // Equivalent to "docker build -f Dockerfile.build --build-arg version=1.0.2 ./build/
    dockerfile {
        filename 'Dockerfile.build'
        dir 'build'
        label 'my-defined-label'
        additionalBuildArgs  '--build-arg version=1.0.2'
        args '-v /tmp:/tmp'
    }
}
```

Comment: Appears to be pasted from "dockerfile" section of https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/